# Django audit log user media file access

Tags: django, audit-logging

I would like to be able to capture an audit log in my database of media file access (download) by users. I'm new to Django so at a loss as to where to start looking at for this, or if this is even possible? Has anyone had any experience or have an ideas they can share as to possible ways I can look into achieving this?

Comment: How are you serving the media files? Are you using nginx?

Comment: Hi Nayan, yes I believe so.

Comment: Then you can add log file in nginx to log certain types of media access events

Comment: Thank you Nayan. I really appreciate the tip. Looking into this I can see I'm going to be able find a solution. Cheers!